# HOW TO Loopback storage setup - AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, loopbackjs

I have tried to follow the [docs](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Storage-component.html)
to get started with loopback 3.x and aws.

Yet, no matter what. this is the response :

`"error": {
    "statusCode": 400,
    "name": "AuthorizationHeaderMalformed",
    "message": "The authorization header is malformed; the Credential is mal-formed; expecting \"<YOUR-AKID>/YYYYMMDD/REGION/SERVICE/aws4_request\".",
    "code": "AuthorizationHeaderMalformed"
  }
}`

I have found [this](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-storage/issues/101)
But i have no idea what is going on there.

have someone solved this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have the key and the keyId in reverse way

AWS_ACCESS_KEY is the equivalent of the keyId and AWS_SECRET_KEY the key.

Comment: This error response had me searching all ends of internet to find solution. Turns out I had the access/secret keys swapped in java config file `new BasicAWSCredentials(secretKey, accessKey)` (wrong) vs `new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)` (correct).